# Predict color of dye under a certain wavelength of light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, absorption, applied-physics

I am picking fluorescent dyes to be put under a UV of known wavelength and would like to be able to predict approximately what color the dyes will appear under the light. I can request spectrophotometer data from the manufacturer. Is there a formula I can use to calculate something like the emission wavelength of the fluorescent dye when it is under the light using information like lamp wavelength, dye absorbance, etc?
The light is only one wavelength that I can't change so sometimes the color seen is different from the color purchased i.e. pink appears orange. If I know the bulb's wavelength and intensity and such, is there a way to predict how the fluoresced color will change under a different light - or are dyes too complex to do this?
If the lamp is 375 nm and I can see that absorbance at 375 nm is 1.23, is there anything I can do with this information?

Comment: They're dayglo dyes and I can't adjust the lamp to a different wavelength

Comment: I think this was and is a perfectly legitimate question and should have remained open - even in its original form. It’s hard, but ultimately answerable.

Comment: There are various profiles of wavelengths that can be mapped to what color humans will perceive. With given information about the reflectivity of the surfaces for specific wavelengths and about the light sources, a mapping of what wavelengths get reflected is also possible. Someone with knowledge about these two mappings should be able to answer even in a generalized case. I’m not that person, but I can see that it can be done. Reopen question. Specific numbers by the asker should not be required.

Comment: Generally the spectrum of fluorescence doesn't depend much on the spectrum of irradiation. E.g. you can shine a blue 460nm laser pointer at an object and see, say, orange fluorescence — and then choose a violet 405nm laser and get the same spectrum of fluorescence. Of course, some of the laser light will be scattered, so you'd get a mixture of the colors of incident light and the emitted one, but still, irradiance alone doesn't tell you the spectrum of fluorescence. You need to get this information about the particular material—emission, not absorbance.

Comment: I found a paper (Spectral Colour Prediction Model for a
Transparent Fluorescent Ink on Paper, Emmel 1998) which provides some guidance. Information required is transmittance, absorption, emission, and quantum yield - most of which I can get from the manufacturer.

Comment: In my experience, lamp does matter but color addition and scattering is probably at play. Lamp A is purplish and dimmer while lamp B is blue and bright. Under A, insect haemolymph is yellow and Blaze Orange is yellowish orange. Under B, haemolymph is green (probably due to the additional blue) and Blaze Orange is purely orange. The haemolymph is tannish clear under white light.